# How to deploy a WebAPI application and an ASP.NET application in one web site on Azure?

Tags: azure

I have two projects: an ASP.NET web application and a WebAPI application.
Web application uses the WebAPI application via AJAX.
To avoid cross domain problem, I want to the two projects deployed under one domain on Azure.
For example:

http://www.mycompany.com/api/products  is a web api.

http://www.mycompany.com/index.html is the home page of the site, which calls the web api via AJAX.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can host multiple applications on the one site.

Go to `Configuration / Virtual Applications and Directories`:
Simply host your app under

```
/     site\wwwroot
```

And host your API under

```
/api  site\wwwroot\api
```

And make sure your API is copied to the `api` sub-directory.

Make sure you tick the `Application` box.